# Single HAProxy frontend for different services

Tags: haproxy

So I'm happily using HAProxy to load balance 2 web servers serving a single service.
Now I need to add 5 more web servers that will respond to 5 different hostnames and I need to use the same frontend as above.

I tried to use ACL with no luck.

I have a test client with hosts file compiled with all hostnames pointing at haproxy and i used something like the following in the frontend:

```
acl hw1 hdr_beg(host) -i hw1.test.lan 

use_backend back_hw1 if hw1
```

Then I set a `back_hw1` backend server but it never seems to match and I get "no response from server" when I try.

All web servers use HTTPS and I correctly set SSL in HAProxy when I setup the first service.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I've tried many acls but i can never seem to match them and i always end up in the default backend. I can post config if you guys need it but i can't seem to be able to match a very simple acl...

Comment: yes plz post the config

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using hdr_beg with what seems to be the FQDN, try hdr_dom(host).

Answer (score 0):

**if** your clients requests are using https you should try to use *sni* acl rather than host header.

Try something like

```
acl hw1 req.ssl_sni -i hw1.test.lan 

use_backend back_hw1 if hw1
```